# Which version of Cassandra and the Thrift API fully supports C#?

Tags: c#, cassandra, thrift

Which version of Cassandra and the Thrift API fully supports C#?

Because the C# source to create the Thrift.dll is currently different from the Java source to generate the Thrift.jar

C# .net here

```
\thrift-0.6.1\lib\csharp\src
```

or [here in the Apache Thrift SVN](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/thrift/trunk/lib/csharp/src/)

Is missing the class TFastFramedTransport which is in the Java source found in this folder

```
\thrift-0.6.1\lib\java\src\org\apache\thrift
```

or [here in the Apache Thrift SVN](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/thrift/trunk/lib/java/src/org/apache/thrift/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the same question of the Thrift mailing list here:

[IFastFramedTransport missing in C# source](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/thrift-user/201107.mbox/browser)

And got this answer:

> FastFramedTransport (in Java) is just
>   a higher-performance FramedTransport.
>   It's not necessary for operation.
>
> As far as when you might see an analog
>   in C#, the answer is probably "when
>   you submit a patch for it." :)
>
> -Bryan

Answer (score 3):

Thrift version 0.6 fully supports C# already.

Cassandra is written in java, but it takes requests from applications through sockets, which is supported by Thrift API to make it easier. So! you just generate Cassandra client by command prompt and use it :), Depend on which programming language you are using for your application

for example, to generate C# Cassandra client:

```
Thrift --gen csharp cassandra.thrift
```

to generate java Cassandra client:

```
Thrift --gen java cassandra.thrift
```

... however, it is *strongly* recommended to use a higher level client like Aquiles or Hector instead of trying to use Thrift directly.  It's not designed for that.

(Re the framed transport specifically, that's been supported from C# [for years](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-210), just not with the exact same class name as Java.)

Comment: When I generate the Thrift code, I also need to reference the Thrift.dll, which is created by compiling another project in the Thrift source. But the C# source is different to the Java source, more specifically, Java includes a class TFastFramedTransport which C# .Net does not. Does this mean that the current C# .Net Thrift source is not up to date?

Comment: I think this is a mistake from Apache thrift team when they delivered there source code : You can find the same mistake in this address : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578411/tfastframedtransort-missing-from-thrift-c-lib